# 'utf-8' decode error when loading a word2vec module

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I have to use a word2vec module containing tons of Chinese characters. The module was trained by my coworkers using Java and is saved as a bin file.

I installed [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) and tries to load the module, but following error occurred:

```
In [1]: import gensim  

In [2]: model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('/data5/momo-projects/user_interest_classification/code/word2vec/vectors_groups_1105.bin', binary=True)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 96-97: unexpected end of data
```

I tried to load the module both in python 2.7 and 3.5, failed in the same way. So how can I load the module in gensim? Thanks.

Comment: your file might be corrupt. First line of the file should have size of vocab and dimensions. Can you do a less and check?

Comment: You can also try converting the binary file to text file using -  https://github.com/marekrei/convertvec

Comment: @kampta, The first line using less the binary file is "202207 200". I guess the bin file is ok. Thanks.

Comment: Did you also try converting the binary file to text file? Was the word2vec module trained using gensim or C word2vec?

Comment: @kampta I ignore the encoding errors when loading the bin file use a flag with unicode_errors='ignore'. See my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module was tons of Chinese characters trained by Java. I cannot figure out the encoding format of the original corpus. The error can be solved as the description in gensim [FAQ](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ#q10-loading-a-word2vec-model-fails-with-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-),

Using load_word2vec_format with a flag for ignoring the character decoding errors:

```
In [1]: import gensim

In [2]: model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('/data5/momo-projects/user_interest_classification/code/word2vec/vectors_groups_1105.bin', binary=True, unicode_errors='ignore')
```

But I've no idea whether it matters when ignoring the encoding errors.

Comment: these are the intricacies that the "embedding" studies ignore. Treat it as if I apply the vectors to unknown words, they will be handled the same as my training data (that ignores unicode errors), so somehow preprocessing for the "test" and "train" is "consistent". Sadly, that's how it works for now =(

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the flag

```
unicode_errors='ignore'
```

but it does not solve the unicode problem.

I checked that I got the unicode error after I rename the file from filename.bin.gz to filename.gz.

My solution is to extract the compressed file, instead of renaming it.

Then I use the file with the flag above and there is no unicode error.

Note that I use Mac (Sierra) with python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat the word2vec file, using the following Java code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

class ReformatW2V {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.err.println("Usage: ReformatW2V inputFileName outputFileName");
            return;
        }

        String inputFileName = args[1];
        String outputFileName = args[2];

        try (
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(inputFileName)), "utf-8"));
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFileName)), "utf-8"))
        ) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] segs = line.split(" ");
                pw.println(String.join(" ", segs));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).