# 'utf8' decode error while loading a word2vec module

Tags: python, utf-8, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I want to use a word2vec module containing tons of Indian characters. The module was trained by Facebook - https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md .
(I am using Gujarati vectors)

I installed gensim and tries to load the module, but following error occurred:

```
In [1]: import gensim  

In [2]: from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('wiki.gu/wiki.gu.bin', binary=True,unicode_errors='ignore')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 32: invalid start byte
```

I tried to load the module both in python 2.7 and 3.5, failed in the same way. So how can I load the module in gensim? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try loading the word2vec using the text file format?

Comment: @AshutoshBaheti Thanks for the reply, I don't have this file in a text format!!

Comment: this is probably a duplicate question. See link below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427678/utf-8-decode-error-when-loading-a-word2vec-module.  Another solution is found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/aWzKlvrXCbE

Comment: @Kashyap its there in the github link you've proveded. [gujrati word vectors text file](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/wiki.gu.vec)

Answer (score 0):

The FastText binary format isn't compatible with Gensim's `word2vec` format; the former contains additional information about subword units, which `word2vec` doesn't make use of.

There's some discussion of the issue (and a workaround), on the FastText Github page. In short, you'll have to load the text format (https://stackoverflow.com/users/4535284/ashutosh-baheti gave you a link in a comment above).

Once you've loaded the text format, you can use Gensim to save it in binary format, which will dramatically reduce the model size, and speed up future loading.

https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/171#issuecomment-294295302